# Picking quartile value on each point

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm plotting sentiment value of tweet over last 10 years.
The csv file has the three columns like below.

I plotted each value by date successfully.
However, when I tried to generate an area graph, 
I encountered a problem which is, 
each date has multiple values.

That's because each data point is from one single tweets that 
one x point ended up with having multiple y values.

So I tried to pick quartile value of each date or pick largest or least y value.
For clarity, please see the example below.

[image]

January 8 has multiple y values (textblob)

I want to draw area graph by picking the largest value or 2nd quartile value of each point.

How do I only pick the point?

I would like to feed the point in the following code as a 
x/y coordinate for line or area greaph.

```
  function* vlinedrawing(data){
         for(let i;i<data.length;i++){
            if( i%500==0) yield svg.node();
            let px = margin+xscale(data[i].date)
            let py = height-margin-yscale(data[i].vader)
            paths.append('path')
            .attr('x',px)
            .attr('y',py)   
     }     
            yield svg.node()  
         }
```

The entire code is in the following link.

https://jsfiddle.net/soonk/uh5djax4/2/

Thank you in advance.
( The reason why it is a generator is that I'm going to visualize the graph in animated way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the 2nd quartile you can use [`d3.quantile`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#quantile) like this:

```
d3.quantile(dataArray, 0.5);
```

Of course, since the 2nd quartile is the median, you can also just use:

```
d3.median(dataArray);
```

But `d3.quantile` is a bit more versatile, you can just change the `p` value for any quartile you want.

Using your data, without parsing the dates (so we can use a `Set` for unique values`), here is a possible solution:

```
const aggregatedData = [...new Set(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.date
}))].map(function(d) {
    return {
      date: parser(d),
      textblob: d3.quantile(data.filter(function(e) {
        return e.date === d
      }).map(function(e) {
        return e.textblob
      }), 0.5)
    }
});
```

This is just a quick answer for showing you the way: that's not a optimised code, because there are several loops within loops. You can try to optimise it.

Here is the demo:

```js
var parser = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%y");

d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jotnajoa/Javascript/master/tweetdata.csv', row).then(function(data) {

  const aggregatedData = [...new Set(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.date
  }))].map(function(d) {
    return {
      date: parser(d),
      textblob: d3.quantile(data.filter(function(e) {
        return e.date === d
      }).map(function(e) {
        return e.textblob
      }), 0.5)
    }
  });

  console.log(aggregatedData)

});

function row(d) {
  d.vader = +d.vader;
  d.textblob = +d.textblob;
  return d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!